# Avro messages not showing up in All Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

Avro messages are showing up in specific partition but not showing up in all Partitions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some more details. Also did you check the total number of expected messages?

Comment: Are your messages keyed?

Comment: How are you sending the messages to Kafka? How many partitions do you have? What key are you setting for your messages?

Comment: Yes. Messages are keyed. We are using some random ObjectId as key.

Comment: We are using Avro producer to send the messages and have 10 partitions.

Comment: The issue is occurring when the no. of messages are increasing.